# I'm getting an error while sending a screenshot

Tags: java, android

As soon as the user clicks the button, I ask him to take a screenshot and send it to another friend.

```
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            View rootView = getWindow().getDecorView().findViewById(android.R.id.content);
            Bitmap bitmap = getScreenShot(rootView);
            File file = store(bitmap,"File-Name");
            shareImage(file);
        }
    });

public static Bitmap getScreenShot(View view) {
    View screenView = view.getRootView();
    screenView.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
    Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(screenView.getDrawingCache());
    screenView.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);
    return bitmap;
}

public static File store(Bitmap bm, String fileName){
    final String dirPath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/Screenshots";
    File dir = new File(dirPath);
    if(!dir.exists())
        dir.mkdirs();
    File file = new File(dirPath, fileName);
    try {
        FileOutputStream fOut = new FileOutputStream(file);
        bm.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 85, fOut);
        fOut.flush();
        fOut.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return file;
}
private void shareImage(File file){
    Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(file);
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    intent.setType("image/*");

    intent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "");
    intent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "");
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);
    try {
        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Share Screenshot"));
    } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "No App Available", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

I see that the bitmap value is "" when I debug. I also have these in my error message.

[Error Log Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7GccN.png)

I used them in my manifest file.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

<provider
    android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
    android:authorities="${applicationId}.provider"
    android:exported="false"
    android:grantUriPermissions="true">
    <meta-data
        android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
        android:resource="@xml/provider_path" />
</provider>
```

Could you please help me?

Comment: Do you want to store this image in a public images folder or temporarily store in a private app folder?

Comment: Hello. I want to use it temporarily

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve the problem with such a structure. Thank you very much to [P Fuster](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8050896/p-fuster) for all his help.

We add these permissions first to the manifests file.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

then we add them to the onCreate method in mainActivity.

```
StrictMode.VmPolicy.Builder builder = new StrictMode.VmPolicy.Builder();
StrictMode.setVmPolicy(builder.build());
```

Now let's give the click effect of our button.

```
share_friends.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            View rootView = getWindow().getDecorView().findViewById(android.R.id.content);
            Bitmap bitmap = getScreenShot(rootView);
            File file = store(bitmap, "name.png");

            if (file.exists()) {
                shareImage(file);
                System.out.println(file.getPath());
            } else {
                Log.e("file exist", "NO");
            }

        }
    });
```

Functions used in the button

```
public static Bitmap getScreenShot(View view) {
    View screenView = view.getRootView();
    screenView.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
    Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(screenView.getDrawingCache());
    screenView.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);
    return bitmap;
}

public File store(Bitmap bm, String fileName) {
    final String dirPath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() + "/Screenshots";
    File dir = new File(dirPath);
    if (!dir.exists())
        dir.mkdirs();
    File file = new File(dirPath, fileName);
    try {
        FileOutputStream fOut = new FileOutputStream(file);
        bm.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 85, fOut);
        fOut.flush();
        fOut.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return file;
}

private void shareImage(File file) {
    Intent shareIntent = new Intent();
    shareIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    shareIntent.setType("image/*");
    shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.fromFile(file));
    shareIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, "Share Screenshot"));
}
```

the problem was solved like this.

Answer (score 0):

You should use this code

```
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                View rootView = getWindow().getDecorView().findViewById(android.R.id.content);
                Bitmap bitmap = getScreenShot(rootView);
                File file = store(bitmap, "name.png");

                if (file.exists()) {
                    shareImage(file);
                } else {
                    Log.e("file exist", "NO");
                }
            }
        });



    public static Bitmap getScreenShot(View view) {
        View screenView = view.getRootView();
        screenView.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
        Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(screenView.getDrawingCache());
        screenView.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);
        return bitmap;
    }

    public File store(Bitmap bm, String fileName) {
        final String dirPath = getExternalCacheDir().getAbsolutePath() + "/Screenshots";
        File dir = new File(dirPath);
        if (!dir.exists())
            dir.mkdirs();
        File file = new File(dirPath, fileName);
        try {
            FileOutputStream fOut = new FileOutputStream(file);
            bm.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 85, fOut);
            fOut.flush();
            fOut.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return file;
    }

    private void shareImage(File file) {
        Intent shareIntent = new Intent();
        shareIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.parse(file.getPath()));
        shareIntent.setType("image/*");
        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, "Share Screenshot"));
    }
```

Comment: Hello. 

I'm getting a  " java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String java.io.File.getAbsolutePath()' on a null object reference " error

Also, the bitmap content is empty again (file:///tmp/Spectacle.wWHVTk/Screenshot_20200906_175756.png)

Answer (score 0):

Use this to capture a bitmap from a view. Your method will not work anymore using the drawing cache.

```
  public drawBitmap(View view, int width, int height) {
        Bitmap bm = Bitmap.createBitmap(width,
                height,
                Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888)

        Canvas canvas = Canvas(bm)
        canvas.drawColor(previewBgColor)

        view.draw(canvas)

        // Store bitmap in dest file,
        File dstFile = File("path/to/file")

        storeBitmap(dstFile, bm)
  }

  public String storeBitmap(File file, Bitmap bmp) {
      FileOutputStream stream;
       try {
          stream = FileOutputStream(file, false)
          bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG,99,it)
       } catch (e: Exception) {
       
       } finally {
          stream.close()
       }

        return file.path
    }
```

If the file exception persists let us know. I am assuming it's giving that error because the bitmap file returns ""? [The docs here should be enough to get you through.](https://developer.android.com/training/sharing/send)

Comment: I couldn't convert your kotlin code to java :( this my code

( --  file:///tmp/Spectacle.wWHVTk/Screenshot_20200906_191113.png -- )

Comment: I'll convert it to Java. Bear with

Comment: I tried the code just like that. there was no problem. However, when I selected whatsapp, I got an "Unsupported file type" error on the device. This is my code
(--> file:///tmp/Spectacle.wWHVTk/Screenshot_20200906_202433.png <--)

Comment: The image is not uploaded, can you use an image hosting website?

Comment: Sorry you need to choose the file path that you want. So replace the "path/to/file";  with getExternalCacheDir().getAbsolutePath() + "/Screenshots/image.jpeg"

Comment: I think I made a mistake. Sorry I kept you busy too. (File.getAbsolutePath ()) returned the following error :(
![Screenshot_20200906_211926](https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/52778108/92332407-a69fdd00-f086-11ea-9549-7c6ba9627c76.png)

Comment: I did Alt + insert and it turned into this shape
![Screenshot_20200906_212229](https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/52778108/92332510-1615cc80-f087-11ea-8c49-757c31a010a9.png)

Comment: You should store it somewhere else actually. Use this: context.getFilesDir().path + "image.jpg" This will give you the apps private files directory located in Android/data/com.yourpackage/files

Comment: I re-selected Whatsapp but got the "Unsupported file type" error. And a few articles appeared in the RUN section. 
![Screenshot_20200906_215803](https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/52778108/92333157-0cdb2e80-f08c-11ea-9cea-be5090b39136.png)

Comment: Oh actually the intent extra EXTRA_STREAM requires a content:// uri.

Comment: Try it with `Uri.parse(file.getPath())`

Comment: thank you for everything. I solved the problem :) [P Fuster](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8050896/p-fuster)

Comment: Glad you found the solution.